# Tkinter Outputs Displaying Outside of Tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running a program that collects data and displaying that data through the outputs (yellow) in my user interface. I delete these outputs by using `Output.pack_forget()` before redisplaying the updated values using

```
Output.insert('end',program_select)
Output.pack()
canvas.create_window(700, 300, window=Output)
```

I continue to do this for several thousand data points. At some point, the outputs no longer update inside the tkinter window, but appear in the top left [enter image description here][1]corner of my screen. I cannot seem to find any pattern as to when the output appears outside of the tkinter window.

My first suspicion was that I was not deleting the previous outputs in the window so I added the `Output.pack_forget()` to delete these, but this "glitch" still occurred.

Excuse me for not uploading my code yet. My program is quite large so I am trying to simplify my code to give a general idea of what is going on.

[Outputs appearing in top-left corner of the screen][1,2]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC5zK.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlP8l.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For widgets that you put in a Canvas object with canvas.create_window you should not be using `pack()` or `pack_forget()` at all. Ever. Delete all of those.

However I don't see any reason you are using a canvas at all.

I also suspect you are making new widgets to cover up the old ones instead of updating the old ones. Doing this will cause your program to lag. We would need to see all your code or at least a minimal runnable example to give specific help with that.

Comment: By <I also suspect you are making new widgets to cover up the old ones instead of updating the old ones.>, do you mean that I should use something like ```Output.insert()``` and ```root.update()``` instead?

Comment: `Output.delete()` and `Output.insert()` yes (assuming Output is an Entry / Text widget). An alternative is using a textvariable which I bet would be a lot easier for you. `root.update()` should never ever be used (unless you really know what you are doing, and then only extremely rarely).